# Installation script for multiple operating systems

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I have to install a `C compiler` with `cilkplus` branch which is recently added to the `GCC`. Since it is recent so I ave to install it manually and there are no direct methods available to that. I plan to install it at custom location. I installed it on a `redhat 6` and `ubuntu 12.04` successfully but I found that the settings of environment variables are different on both operating systems ( not a surprise ).

For example to install the compiler on `ubuntu 12.04` you would need `C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` a directory which does not exist on `redhat 6`.

I plan to write a single script for installation of this compiler on many systems(different distributions of linux). How can I do it.

One way I can think of is to check which OS and version you are running and set `environment variables` accordingly but here also I do not know how to do it.

Any other suggestions are also valueable.
Thanks

Comment: So are you asking how to check the OS and version? Or what are you asking, exactly?

Comment: If you really want 'single script ... on many systems' check out the pair of tools `autoconf` and `configure`. This is one well documented system for performing unix like installs. but warning, it can often be a frustrating and time-consuming process. There are other packages that support installing packages, but, because of the nature of the install-a-package-with-a-highly-variable-toolset problem, they can be problematic to use too. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would use cmake for easy dependency checking and handling